# Python 'def' returning 'None'?

Tags: python, function

I'm new to python and I'm writing some really simple code just for practice. I'm trying to write a function that returns True or False if an input year is a leap year or not.

My output for the year 2020 for example is:

```
True
None
```

but it just want it to be `True` - what is happening?

Code below:

```
def is_leap(year):
    if year%4 !=0:
        print('False')
    elif year%100 == 0:
        print('False')
    elif year%100 == 0 and year%400 == 0:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('True')
    return
year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Comment: `return` and `print` are two different things. You might want to `return True` or r`return False` instead of printing and remove the last return statement

Comment: `print(is_leap(year))` is printing the returned value from the function, which since you just have `return`, it defaults to `None`

Comment: try this

```
def isleap(year): 
      
         if (year%4 == 0) or  (year%400 == 0 or ((year%4 == 0) & (year%100 !=0))): 
             return True
         else: 
             return False 
                                 


```

Answer (score 2):

Python is indent sensitive. You should indent everything within your function block.

Also you don't return anything in your `is_leap` function.

You might want to do

```
def is_leap(year):
    if year%4 !=0:
        return False
    elif year%100 == 0:
        return False
    elif year%100 == 0 and year%400 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: When I run this for any year, I don't get any output

Comment: I have to disagree. When I try the code from this answer as a replacement for your `def is_leap(year)` I **do** get output.

Comment: @HenriettaShalansky you must pair this function with a print statement:

`print('Is Leap Year {0}'.format(is_leap(2020)))`

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating `print` and `return`:

```
def is_leap(year):

    if year%4 != 0:
        return 'False'
    elif year%100 == 0:
        return 'False'
    elif year%100 == 0 and year%400 == 0:
        return 'True'
    return 'True'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not use strings and instead use booleans?

Comment: Yes, but one change at a time.

Comment: I genuinely don't know how to response to that

Comment: Sorry :/ why would it be better to use strings?

Comment: I mean my code is the smallest change to get the required effect. Its not clear whether the OP wants booleans or strings given the result is printed.

Comment: @quamrana you introduced stringified booleans, OP was just printing out values.

Comment: I think the OP started with strings eg: `print('False')`

Comment: Regardless, it's bad practice to use types as other types (strings as booleans) and "one change at a time" is not a good reasoning to keep it as such. Remember we're here to teach the best practices, that little above and beyond makes a big difference :)

Comment: One change at a time aka Baby Steps.